# prevent a button being clicked consecutively in React

Tags: reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

I am trying to prevent a button being clicked consecutively in my project and only allow a single click. I would also like it to only be a single click and not allow a double click if that is possible?

To do this I would like to add a time out of maybe 5 seconds before the button can be pressed again but I'm not sure how to do this. The button is a link to redirect the user back to the homepage.

Is the a way to set the button on a timer when clicked?

```
<Button id="back-btn" variant="link" className="btn btn-link" onClick={props.goBack} alt="homepage">
Homepage
</Button>
```

Any ideas?
Cheers
R

Answer (score 4):

basically you need to use a disabled state with a timer.

check this codepen: https://codepen.io/hasanagh/pen/MWaLxVK

```
  state = {
    disabled: false,
  };

  handleButtonClicked = () => {
    //going back logic
    this.setState({
      disabled: true,
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState(() => ({
          disabled: false,
        }));
      }, 5000);
  };

  render() {
    const { disabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <button   
        onClick={this.handleButtonClicked}
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        Button to be disabled
      </button>
    );
  }
```

Also, not sure why you need it to be 5 sec if this is related to a certain event better bind to event than time.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably most re-useable to make your button component. You could handle the `onClick` event to set a `disabled` state, then start a timer to set it back to false. Example:

```
const DebouncedButton = ({ as = button, delay, onClick, ...props }) => {
  const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isDisabled) {
      // timeout elapsed, nothing to do
      return;
    }

    // isDisabled was changed to true, set back to false after `delay`
    const handle = setTimeout(() => {
      setDisabled(false);
    }, delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(handle);
  }, [isDisabled, delay]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (isDisabled) {
      return;
    }

    setDisabled(true);
    return onClick(e);
  };

  const Component = as;
  return <Component {...props} disabled={isDisabled} onClick={handleClick} />;
};
```

You would use this component just like you'd use a button, except that you pass it a `delay` which is the amount of time in milliseconds it should be disabled after clicking. The `as` prop lets you pass the component which is used for the button itself, defaulting to `<button>`.

```
<DebouncedButton
  as={Button}
  delay={5000}
  id="back-btn"
  variant="link"
  className="btn btn-link"
  onClick={() => console.log('click!')}
  alt="homepage"
/>
```

Currently it sets the `disabled` property of the button to `true`, but if you don't want the visual, just remove `disabled={isDisabled}` from the component.